# Erro 500 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: htaccess

estou com um problema no htaccess

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^login/$ /login.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zuo/index.php?acao=busca&q=$1 [L]
```

no log de erros aparece

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration e$tion error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
```

quando removo 
RewriteRule ^login/$ /login.php [L]
da certo!

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 3):

Isto ocorre porque você não adicionou uma configuração para verificar se a página já é a index.php.

No caso isto `^(.*)$` significa qualquer página deve ser direcionada

No caso acredito que você tenha tentado usar `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` para verificar se a página já veio de um redirecionamento, mas não funcionou como o esperado.

**Nota:** Não use o `/` na frente de:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^login/$ /login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zuo/index.php?acao=busca&q=$1 [L]
```

Use assim:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ zuo/index.php?acao=busca&q=$1 [L]
```

Ao invés de usar o `RewriteCond` você pode tentar usar um RegEx assim `^(?!(index\.php)(/.*|)|login/.*|login.php)(.*)$` que irá ignorar se começar com `index.php` ou `index.php/path`

O resultado:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!(zuo\/index\.php|login/.*|login.php))(.*)$ zuo/index.php?acao=busca&q=$2 [L]
```

Não cheguei a testar, mas a lógica é está.